# User can't added into cart product without user is login

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have use theme is woodmart theme, I improve only login user added product in to cart page, how attached code of this but it cannot work.

```
function custom_add_to_cart_redirect($url) {
    if (is_user_logged_in() && !is_admin()) {
        if (isset($_GET['product_id']) && isset($_GET['quantity'])) {
            $product_id = sanitize_text_field($_GET['product_id']);
            $quantity = intval($_GET['quantity']);
            if (wc_get_product($product_id)) {
                WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity);
                $url = wc_get_cart_url();
            }
        }
    } else {
        $url = 'http://localhost:8080/wptest/my-account/';
    }
    return $url;
}
add_filter('add_to_cart_redirect', 'custom_add_to_cart_redirect');
```

My woocommerce setting product reference:

Checkout setting image

Site: `https://laundry-line.com`

How can I improve this code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation` hook:

```
function so_validate_add_cart_item( $passed, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id = '', $variations= '' ) {

    // do your validation, if not met switch $passed to false
    if (is_user_logged_in() && !is_admin()) {
        if (isset($_GET['product_id']) && isset($_GET['quantity'])) {
            $product_id = sanitize_text_field($_GET['product_id']);
            $quantity = intval($_GET['quantity']);
            if (wc_get_product($product_id)) {
                WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity);
                $url = wc_get_cart_url();
                $passed = true;
            }
        }
    } else {
        $passed = false;
        wc_add_notice( __( 'You can not do that', 'textdomain' ), 'error' );
    }
    return $passed;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'so_validate_add_cart_item', 10, 5 );
```

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'add_the_date_validation', 11, 2 ); 
function add_the_date_validation( $passed, $product_id ) {

    if (is_user_logged_in() && !is_admin()) {
        if (isset($_GET['product_id']) && isset($_GET['quantity'])) {
            $product_id = sanitize_text_field($_GET['product_id']);
            $quantity = intval($_GET['quantity']);
            if (wc_get_product($product_id)) {
                WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity);
                $url = wc_get_cart_url();
                $passed = true;
                wp_safe_redirect($url);
                exit();
            }
        }
    } else {
        $url = 'http://localhost:8080/wptest/my-account/';
        wp_safe_redirect($url);
        exit();
    }
}
```

Also change the setting like below:

[image]

Comment: thankyou vel, it's working fine.. but can i add in this else it's not login then redirect link to the direct my-account page. 

this redirect link : https://laundry-line.com/my-account/
Example image: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/41942370?key=7b88f7ee717cdc375a13c5e426322e3c